Post Requests failing with Metriport Webhook
Hi I'm trying to connect my app to metriport webhook api View Doc.
I have tried to implement the post api through Express js and I am trying to use ngrok to expose my local server to the internet for testing webhooks. However, I'm encountering an issue where ngrok returns a 404 error for POST requests.
I have checked my server logs, and it appears that the POST requests are not reaching my server at all when going through ngrok. GET requests seem to work fine.
Is there something I need to configure differently in ngrok or my server to properly handle POST requests through ngrok? Any help would be appreciated.
Here is my app.js
var app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

const webhookRouter = require('./routes/webhook');
app.use('/webhook', webhookRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});



app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Route to handle POST requests from Metriport's webhook
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
  // Process the incoming data from Metriport
  console.log('Received webhook payload:', req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200); // Send a success response
});


module.exports = app;

And here is my webhook.js in route folder of Express Js server:
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const crypto = require('crypto');

// Function to verify the webhook signature
function verifySignature(signature, body, secret) {
    const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret);
    const digest = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(body)).toString('hex');
    const computedSignature = hmac.update(digest).digest('hex');
    return signature === computedSignature;
}

// Route for handling webhook POST requests
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const signature = req.headers['x-metriport-signature'];
    const secret = 'secret_key'; // Replace with your actual webhook secret
    const isValid = verifySignature(signature, req.body, secret);

    if (!isValid) {
        console.error('Invalid signature');
        return res.sendStatus(403); // Forbidden
    }

    // Process the incoming webhook payload
    const message = req.body;
    if (message.type === 'ping') {
        // Respond to the ping message
        return res.json({ pong: message.ping });
    }

    // For other message types, handle accordingly
    console.log('Received webhook payload:', message);
    res.sendStatus(200); // Send a success response
});

module.exports = router;

